# Blender to FBX animation export for use in 3ds max

Tags: export

Whenever i export a blender animation to FBX format, and then import it into 3DS Max, 3DS Max only shows 180 frames even though my animation is 600 frames long.
I even tried changing the Timeline in Max but it didn't work.

Please can someone help me?

I used settings for exporting -
Version - FBX 6.1 ASCII
and others have their default values.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Sincerely.